# Is it possible to change the randomText function into arrow function?

Tags: javascript

I have read about the arrow function and wonder if it is possible and whether it is worth converting this function to the arrow function. I tried and unfortunately, I failed. I would like a hint on this topic.

```
 export const randomText = function randomtext (length) {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
           result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
     }
```

Comment: Simply replace `function randomtext (length) {` with `(length) => {`. What were you having trouble with ?

Comment: It’s generally a bad idea to create custom functions with the exact name of built-in functions. Use a new name for your new thing; it will avoid a lot of confusion and frustration down the road

Comment: or, if you have only one parameter, `length => {`. No need to be so aggressive though

Comment: @natsuozawa Actually, I was genuinely asking the question because if OP is having a trouble with this it might be because of a misunderstanding, which may create more issue for them later

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
function randomtext (length) {
```

to this:

```
(length) => {
```